# Google Sheets IMPORTXML query

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets as web scraper.

I have been using this IMPORTXML

`=importxml(A1, "//div[@class='review-content']//text()")`

and this is the results

```
Row1: {"publishedDate":"2019-01-05T22:19:28Z","updatedDate":"null","reportedDate":"null}

Row2: {"publishedDate":"2018-12-10T22:19:28Z","updatedDate":"null","reportedDate":"null}

Row3: {"publishedDate":"2018-12-09T22:19:28Z","updatedDate":"null","reportedDate":"null}
```

but am having trouble figuring out how to get only the "publishedDate" value.
Example:

```
Row1: 2019-01-05T22:19:28Z

Row2: 2018-12-10T22:19:28Z

Row3: 2018-12-09T22:19:28Z
```

Any ideas as to what I may be missing

Comment: What is the URL of the XML that you are importing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about these 3 samples? I thought them from the samples of your question. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as 3 samples of them.

It supposes that the URL is put in the cell "A1".

#### Sample 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MID(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='review-content']//text()"),19,20))
```

- When the length of string of each value is the constant, how about this?

  - The value is retrieved by `MID()`.

#### Sample 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='review-content']//text()"),"""",TRUE,TRUE),,4))
```

- When the position of each value is the constant, how about this?

  - The value is retrieved by `SPLIT()` and `INDEX()`.

#### Sample 3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='review-content']//text()"),"publishedDate"":""(\w.+?)"""))
```

- When the pattern of each value is the constant, how about this?

  - The value is retrieved by `REGEXEXTRACT()`.

#### References:

- [MID](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

If these were not the results you want, I apologize. At that time, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the URL you are using as [@Rubén](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%c3%a9n) says?

Comment: All the samples the you provided works fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @mauro Bros Thank you for your response.